# Coupon not valid for non loggedin users

Tags: magento2, coupon

I'm setting up a sale rule with a coupon which is £10 off if you spend more than £50.

While logged in this seems to work fine however when not logged in the coupon code is flagged as invalid.

http://prntscr.com/lxue5f is a screenshot of the Customer Group rule were everything is added and I'm unable to see any errors for non logged in users.

Comment: try to disable other rules, only active your coupon rule.

Comment: @JimitBhavsar I've tested this but still the same results.

Comment: Disable the third party and custom module and check.